# Editing status message contents

Tags: 7, commerce, status-messages

I want to change the contents of a status message, it is being brought in via the [commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module (`commerce_cart.rules.inc`).

The error message I want to change is:

```
/**
* Rules action: displays a the default translatable Add to Cart message.
*/
function commerce_cart_rules_add_to_cart_message($product) {
  drupal_set_message(t('%title added to <a href="!cart-url">your cart</a>.', array('%title' => $product->title, '!cart-url' => url('cart'))));
}
```

I don't want to apply a patch to commerce just to change a status message so does anyone know of any alternate solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the default `Display a translatable Add to Cart message` action and add a custom message that you want to be displayed yourself.

You can do this at `/admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/manage/commerce_cart_add_to_cart_message`.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way is to use the module [stringoverides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides).

- Extract to your sites/all/modules directory.
- Enable the module in admin/build/modules.
- Configure the access permission in admin/user/access or admin/user/permissions.
- Visit admin/settings/stringoverrides or admin/config/regional/stringoverrides and fill in the strings you'd like to replace.

For this question you have to replace

```
%title added to <a href="!cart-url">your cart</a>
```

into that what you want.

Comment: How to do so ???

Comment: As it is, this is just a comment. If you were giving more information, it could be an answer.